# Possible to mount a specific directory on Linux server to a local Windows machine?

Tags: windows, linux, mount

I have a directory on my server at

/home/dave/www/images/site (ext3)

which I want to mount directly to my Windows computer so that I can transfer data easily via command line tool. Is that something possible?

Comment: Is this server located in your "local" network or across the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server is local, you may want to look into creating Samba shares, which will behave exactly like a standard Windows share if configured correctly.

FTP and SCP also come to mind. If this server will be reached across the internet, I would highly recommend SCP.

[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline) has a great command-line utility, as well as a corresponding graphical version.

Comment: Thanks man WinSCP looks like will do the trick. Putty was an option but WinSCP does the job well too.

Answer (score 1):

If the server is located within your "local" network (i.e: not across the internet) it might actually be considerably less hassle to set up a SMB (i.e.: Windows) share on the Linux server and let your Windows box access it in that manner.

Depending on your server configuration, if may already have the necessary software (Samba) installed - check your package manager for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these links on using Samba:

[Install Samba Server on Ubuntu](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-samba-server-on-ubuntu/)

[Configuring SAMBA](https://help.ubuntu.com/6.06/ubuntu/serverguide/C/configuring-samba.html)

[The Unofficial Samba HOWTO](http://www.oregontechsupport.com/samba/)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be scp/sftp. If you have an SSH server running on the Linux machine  you can use scp/sftp tools to transfer files (such as putty - http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html):

```
C:\> pscp image.gif dave@linuxhost:www/images/site
```