# Mount remote UNIX directory in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, unix, mount

I have ssh access to a UNIX machine. I was wondering if there was a way to mount my home directory as a windows drive, so that I'm able to edit the UNIX files with in windows. Any free software would be fine. I've seen [this](https://superuser.com/questions/235882/possible-to-mount-a-specific-directory-on-linux-server-to-a-local-windows-machin) question, but what I want is a drive mounted with UNIX directory.

Thanks 
    Jvc

Comment: Try http://sshdrive.com/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but sshdrive says that windows 7 is not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I found out [win-sshfs](https://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/). It do have option of mounting UNIX directory as a Windows local drive, and has support for Windows 7.