# Is there a way to mount a remote server on my local dekstop

Tags: remote-access

I have a university server that I can log into via putty and "ls" gives me all my files and stuff. However, I occasionally (regularly) need to work on these files from home. I would like a solution to this. I was thinking

1) Can I mount a folder on my Windows 7 box so that when I open the folder it "runs, 'ls' in the background and lists all files for me in a GUI"

2) Can I download these files via putty but then upload them back when I am done updating them (I would actually not like to do this)

Thanks

Comment: Got my answer at http://superuser.com/questions/458131/mount-remote-unix-directory-in-windows-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you connect to this server via SSH.

You can use a utility such as win-sshfs as suggested by @masfenix.  Seems to depend on the Dokan libraries.

You can also check out [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) - it works more like an FTP client than a folder on your desktop but isn't difficult to use (drag and drop works OK).

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

```
1. Map Network Drive
2. Click "Connect to a Web Site..."
3. Follow on-screen instructions until you get to the network address
   a. Type ftp://yourschoolsaddres:22
   b. Uncheck "Log In Anonymously"
   c. Type your user name and click next
   d. Click next and log out
4. It will ask you for your password every time but there you go!
```